# Intermittent Axios Network Error on Image Upload with React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post, axios, expo

I'm working on a React Native project using Expo (version ^50.0.7) and encountering a challenging issue with intermittent network errors when uploading images using Axios. The function responsible for uploading the user's profile picture to my server works correctly most of the time, but occasionally (about every 4-5 uploads), it fails with an "Axios Network Error."

Interestingly, when I perform the same request using Postman, it works flawlessly every time, which leads me to believe the issue lies within the frontend of my application.

**Here are the details of what I've tried so far:**

1. My requests target my IP address, not localhost, to avoid typical local network issues.
2. Experimented with changing Content-Type to content-type.
3. Played around with the formData values.
4. Updated Axios to different versions to see if the issue persists, which it does.
5. Addressed potential CORS issues on the backend, but the problem remains.

**Below is a simplified version of my image upload function:**

```
const handleUpload = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const token = await getFromAsyncStorage(Keys.AUTH_TOKEN);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://<my-ip-address>/auth/profile-image-upload",
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;",
        },
      }
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**And here's how I prepare the formData:**

```
// Request camera permissions
const hasPermission = await requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
if (!hasPermission) return;

// Open the camera with ImagePicker
const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    cameraType: ImagePicker.CameraType.front,
    allowsEditing: true, // Allows editing the picture
    aspect: [1, 1], // Square aspect ratio
    quality: 0.2, // Quality
});

// If the user doesn't cancel, set the selected image
if (result.canceled) return;

setIsLoading(true);

const file = result.assets[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("avatar", {
    uri: file.uri,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: "profile",
} as any);

const data = await handleUpload(formData);
```

Given that this error does not occur with every upload attempt and never happens with Postman, I'm at a loss for what else to try. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into potential solutions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the endpoint http or https? I don't the issue is with axios tbh.

Comment: Hi, The endpoint is http. I've verified that the server accepts requests correctly via Postman. and also it works most of the time. In addition, I notice that the problem continues both on physical devices and in the android studio simulator.

Comment: Well somehow apis are working always just fine with Postman. Because of the security concerns on web and mobile apps, react mandate https requests. Try adding ssl certification and I'm pretty sure your problem will be resolved.